# Why are children models added to both parent models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an example below that creates two parent models and then uses an custom function to push a child model into an array of the parent.

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/hamuro/4/edit?html,console

```
var Child = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        children: []
    },
    addChild: function() {
      var child = new Child();
      this.get('children').push(child);
      return child;
    }
  });

  var parent1 = new Parent();
  var parent2 = new Parent();

  parent2.addChild();
  parent2.addChild();

  console.log('Parent 1 Total Children: ' + parent1.get('children').length);
  console.log('Parent 2 Total Children: ' + parent2.get('children').length);
```

**Expected Output:**

"Parent 1 Total Children: 0"

"Parent 2 Total Children: 2"

**Actual Output:**

"Parent 1 Total Children: 2"

"Parent 2 Total Children: 2"

**Question:**

Why are children being pushed to both parent models even though I have only specified children be pushed to parent2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they share a single `children` array: When the defaults are set, they're set by assignment, and what gets assigned is a reference to the array, not a *copy* of the array. E.g., for the same reason that `a` and `b` below refer to the same array:

```
var a = [];
var b = a;
```

...just rather less directly via the `defaults` mechanism.

Instead, you specify a `defaults` *function*, which gets called each time to create a distinct array:

`defaults` function:

```
var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() [
    return {
      children: []
    };
  },
  addChild: function() {
    var child = new Child();
    this.get('children').push(child);
    return child;
  }
});
```

This is what [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) is talking about when it says:

> Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances. Instead, define `defaults` as a function.

It may also be possible to do this using a `constructor` instead, but I won't show an example because I don't use Backbone and could easily show something misleading (and the docs point to using a `defaults` function, so they probably have a reason).

Comment: Thanks for that clear explanation. I hadn't even considered the issue was related to settings the defaults that way.